# Call function contained within React component from outside the component

Tags: reactjs

I have a react component that basically handles forms and all the various complexity that comes with certain types of form fields.

Within the component I have a function that can submit the form. This submit function does some validation and then updates the Redux store to say it has been submitted, and then I have a listener type function to monitor that change and call the required backend apis.

```js
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';
import ReactForm from '@my-company/react-forms-package';

window.addEventListener('load', () => {

    const dataAttributeName = 'data-react-form-schema';
    const domRootContainers = document.querySelectorAll('['+dataAttributeName+']');

    let formSchema;
    domRootContainers.forEach((root) => {

        formSchema = root.getAttribute(dataAttributeName);
        if (! formSchema) return console.error('Missing form schema.');

        formSchema = JSON.parse(formSchema);        

        createRoot(root).render(
            <ReactForm formSchema={formSchema} />
        );
    });

});
```

My question is how do I interact with this component from the outside? Within the < ReactForm /> elem is the submit function which I could export? I basically just want to call this submit function from within the JS file above and still have it update this components redux store. I feel I might be breaking a pattern doing this, but for my specific circumstances it would be super useful.